# How can I get a nodejs server to restart with a graph update in Flowhub/noflo-ui?

Tags: noflo

I've noticed that when using the nodejs runtime with noflo/Flowhub, a server restart is necessary for it to catch many graph changes. I've experimented with using [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon), but I'm unsure which files/folders I should have it watch in order to reliably catch graph updates. Is there a known "best method" for this?

UPDATE: Since learning this was a bug, I tried switching to a different version of node.js. Previously I was using v0.12.4 - I have since switched to v0.10.2 and am no longer experiencing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If server restarts are required for reflecting graph changes that is a bug. Please file with details on Github.

There are no files changed on disk when graph changes are sent to the runtime, so I do not see how it would be possible to use file monitoring to work around such bugs.